# adding multiplied numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function multiplyBy()
{
        num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
       num3= document.getElementById("result").value = num1 * num2;
       document.getElementById("total").value = +num3 ;
}
```

```html
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" value="" onchange="multiplyBy()" /><br>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="result" id = "result" value=""/>
</p>
<p>Total :<br>
<input type="text" name="total" id="total" value=""/>
</p>
```

```js
function multiplyBy()
{
        num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
       num3= document.getElementById("result").value = num1 * num2;
}
```

```html
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" value="" 
onchange="multiplyBy()" /><br>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="result" id = "result" value=""/>
</p>
```

I am multiplying two numbers here.how to add those multiplied numbers in another text box.suppose 2&5 are multiplied later 4&6 multiplied how to add those numbers.

Comment: when do you want them to add?

Comment: when I get the result of multiplying two numbers i will do another multiplication, the previous multiplied number must add to present multiplied number in another text field.

Comment: @chakri in your first snippet change `document.getElementById("total").value = +num3 ;` to `document.getElementById("total").value += num3 ;`

Comment: its taking the values as string in adding operation.when i want add previous result 6 to the present result 20 ,,it showing like 620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need to parse the input value using [`parseFloat`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCv4nXlKbUAhXFNI8KHQG4CUMQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g&sig2=6LUXbZDtq3jo-IXComJqXA). This will convert the string to a number. The existing result value is added to the newly calculating value. `|0` is used for the false value of input getting 0

**Updated**

1. prev, present and total result box were added

Append each additional input with new result.

```js
var last=0;
function multiplyBy() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber");
  var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber");
  var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
  var present = document.getElementById("present");
  var total = document.getElementById("result");
  prev.value=last;
  present.value=(parseFloat(num1.value) * parseFloat(num2.value))
  last = last+(parseFloat(num1.value) * parseFloat(num2.value))
  total.value=last;
  num1.value = ""; 
  num2.value = "";

  }
```

```html
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="" /><br> 2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" value="" onchange="multiplyBy()" /><br>
<p >
Prev result:<br>
<input type="text" name="result"  id="prev" ><br>
Present:<br>
<input type="text" name="result"  id="present" ><br>
The total Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="result"  id="result"><br>
</p>
```

Comment: i mean if i do two multiplication operationd the previous value must add to present value in another text field

Comment: Another text field means another one result box

Comment: @chakri check my updated answer. I was added code for append with new text fileld with addition value

Comment: You are just adding Explanation was unclear .What you want

Comment: for example when i multiply 2*3 answer will be 6.and again i will do same operation like 4*3 then result will be 12.now in in "Total" text field i want the value as 6+12 i.e 18.

Comment: i want some modification like the adding operation must perform in another text field can you  help me with that.

Comment: i mean i dont want to extend the text boxes those values will add in one box only

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event handlers if you want to calculate on change of textbox input like following.

```js
function multiplyBy()
{
     var result = document.getElementById("result");
      var  num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
       var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
     
     var num3= parseFloat(num1) * parseFloat(num2);// to convert entered values to float and || 0 to  use 0 if no value is there
       
       if(!isNaN(num3)){
          document.getElementById("resultPrev").value =   document.getElementById("result").value;
           document.getElementById("resultCurrent").value =   num3;
             result.value =  parseFloat(result.value || 0) + num3;
       }
        
       
}


document.getElementById("firstNumber").addEventListener("change",multiplyBy);


document.getElementById("secondNumber").addEventListener("change",multiplyBy);
```

```html
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" /><br>
<p>The Previous Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="resultPrev" id = "resultPrev" value="0"/>
</p>
<p>The Current Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="resultCurrent" id = "resultCurrent" value=""/>
</p>
<p>The Final Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="result" id = "result" value=""/>
</p>
```

Consider handling non number values.

Comment: can you pls explain.when I get the result of multiplying two numbers i will do another multiplication, the previous multiplied number must add to present multiplied number in another text field.

Comment: no if i do two multiplication operationd the previous result must add to present reswult in another text field

Comment: check update! You can attempt assigning the result to the required inputs and change the code as per requirement :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have added the multiplyBy() to both the input fields and changed the type to number to restrict the user to enter number only.

Please check the code snippet below.

```js
document.getElementById("firstNumber").addEventListener("change",multiplyBy);
document.getElementById("secondNumber").addEventListener("change",multiplyBy);

function multiplyBy()
    {
    actualResult = document.getElementById("actualResult").value ? document.getElementById("actualResult").value : 0; // Return zero if there is no value in actualResult input field
            num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
            num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;       
           num3= document.getElementById("result").value = num1 * num2;
 document.getElementById("actualResult").value = Number(actualResult) + num3;  
    }
```

```html
 1st Number : <input type="number" id="firstNumber" value=""/><br>
    2nd Number: <input type="number" id="secondNumber" value=""/><br>
    <p>The Current Result is : <br>
    <input type="number" name="result" id = "result" value=""/>
 </p>
   <p>Previous Result + Current Result : <br> 
    <input type="number" name="actualResult" id = "actualResult" value=""/>
    </p>
```

Comment: thanks this is what i want , its working fine in code snippet but not working on my eclipse.

Comment: While running in the code snippet editor the javascript automatically gets appended in the body, thats why it works in code snippet editor. For making it work in you code, use "addEventListener" method. Please have a look into the modified example and remove the onchange attribute from html

Comment: Please up vote the answer if you this has helped you, so that this might help others too

Comment: thanks for your support can you explain why you use  number in this Number(actualResult) + num3;

Comment: During multiplication the multiples are implicitly type casted to number by JavaScript. But in case of addition it's not, the value passed from HTML is always considered as String by Javascript and addition of strings happen, when trying to add actualResult and num3. So to convert this to addition of numbers explicit typecasting is done, like Number(actualResult). When this is done the second multiple, num3 is implicitly type casted to number by Javascript. Hope you understood. The same result will be result while we perform parseInt(actualResult, 10),parsing to integer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need for get value of text box and add it with result

```
function multiplyBy()
{       var sum = 0;
        var num=0; 
        num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
        num2 = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
        num =parseInt(num1 * num2);
        num3=parseInt(document.getElementById("result").value);
        document.getElementById("result").value=(num + num3);

}
</script>
1st Number : <input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="" /><br>
2nd Number: <input type="text" id="secondNumber" value="" 
onchange="multiplyBy()" /><br>
<p>The Result is : <br>
<input type="text" name="result" id = "result" value="0"/>
</p>
```

Comment: no if i do two multiplication operationd the previous value must add to present value

Comment: have you set Zero default  value to result text box                              
        <input type="text" name="result" id = "result" value="0"/>